# Child travelling abroad and money

Tags: international-travel, money, children

My child will be traveling to Paris in 2022 on an escorted school trip (he will then be 13). Does anyone have experience in the best/easiest/safest way to provide a minor money while they travel?  Should I give him cash, a prepaid debit card, add him as a user to my credit card, use Moneygram?

Comment: He probably won't need much money, will he? Cash is probably the easiest option, though a prepaid debit card could be useful in some situations.

Comment: Please talk to his school, they should be taking care of everything since it is a school trip, unless he wants to spend something for his own like buying something

Comment: It's worth checking out some prepaid cards that can offer ATM withdrawal and international transactions. You don't say where you're based so not sure if it's applicable but accounts like Revolut Junior might be worth looking into (where you can remotely top it up if needed; not affiliated & don't have kids! Have just heard of it). I think some other pre-paid Mastercard allow international ATM withdrawal, which could be a good balance for safety — cash is available for smaller shops but don't need to be worried about loss/theft of larger amounts.

Comment: Do you use Euros in your country? The best way may depend on this. (e.g. Revolut/Transferwise and similar might be better at the exchange)

Comment: "My child will be traveling to Paris in 2022" - such confidence...

Comment: How long is the trip? What actually needs to get paid by the child in person? Pretty much everything they need - food, transportation etc. should be paid by the school, so for what -- except souvenirs -- does the child need money? That'll determine the amount, and thus have great influence on whats the best options. personally, I've always used cash until I got my own EC card when I was 14.

Comment: I'm still owing my tax declaration for 2019 and you are chiseling out the last details of your son's school trip in **2022** !? That is beyond my event horizon for about *anything.* (I'm mostly good at things that can be done in one afternoon.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, being prepared is not strange. It is not certain this travel will get on, but why not ask when you think about it.

Comment: At that age, 13, the chaperones might even be in charge of keeping the money for safety reason.

Comment: @Max, it is possible, certainly with American schools, but my knowledge with European school trips is that kids keep their own money (and the parents are told how much or little money the kids should get.)

Comment: Traveling from where?

Comment: @Max I've never heard of that in the US

Comment: Cheques are not accepted everywhere, and getting to a bank or a Moneygram agent might be challenging, especially when travelling in a group. I had to cash in a cheque once while I was in Paris (I am from Germany), went to a bank and they refused to take my cheque at first, then led me to the manager's office when i insisted, who then authorized that transaction. All that with me speaking English and being answered solely in French. I also had ATMs "eat my card" while travelling. So I prefer to have a sufficient amount of cash always at hand, even when travelling in my own country.

Comment: A note on credit cards: pay attention to the cost of foreign currency transactions. I have one credit card that charges a 3% fee for foreign-currency charges and one that charges 0% (I _think_ they both exchange at the same rate). 3% can really add up, though.

Comment: Did we ever get an answer as to whether the child is traveling to Paris from some other city in France, some other country in the EU, some non-EU European country that uses Euros, some European country that does not use Euros, some non-European country? Whether multiple currencies are involved? Whether the OP's child comes from a country where children can have their own monetary plastic?

Answer (score 30):

Most schools will let you know how much money to give for the trip.

Most of the time they will also tell how, cash, card or other methods.

How much depends on what the kids have to pay, how much you allow as extra money and you will likely adjust the method to the amount.

If it is just a small amount, for some souvenirs and the odd snack, cash in euros is still the easiest. Unless the kid already has a card that will work in Paris.
If the kids have to pay for lunch cash and/or a prepaid card.

I would not give a teen a credit card, certainly not without a limit on it.
Besides, for the small amounts I expect a teen on a school trip to need, credit cards may not be accepted. (Although the comments on this and other answers indicate that in France credit cards and debit/bank cards on the Mastercard and Visa systems are all accepted in all places that accept cards, but there might be a minimum amount depending on the place.)

If your kid already has a smart way to pay, like a phone or watch, that might work.

If the school tells to bring cash and each kid has to arrange their own, see if you can get other parents to work together, saving effort and money on the transaction. Or ask around whether friends or family members still have euros and you can buy them for the market price without having to pay a bank, good for both parties. (Internet does give good values, just search  pound to euro or dollar to euro or whatever.)

Some school trips have a teacher collect the money at the start and handing it out once a day, or more often, on request. This basically works with cash but some schools may accept money in a bank and hand it out in cash, so if the kids need to have quite a bit of money that might be worth asking.

Comment: Yes, the school should have guidelines about money.

Comment: And if you opt for cash, although it may be obvious to most on here, it may be worth being explicit: if your home currency is not the Euro, you should give your child Euros (i.e. convert the currency yourself) rather than have a 13 year old attempt to change money while on a trip.

Comment: @David I would also add that you should shop around if possible when looking for the currency conversion. Different financial institutions will charge different amounts (though almost always more than the exchange rate would suggest), so you may be able to save a bit of money if multiple banks in your area do currency conversions. Of course, the search may have to go pretty far afield depending on where the OP lives.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn certainly 2 years ago buying Euros in the UK the top few rates were so close together for getting £200-worth that merely starting the car to drive to somewhere with a better rate would cost you more than it would save.  Pre-ordering at a supermarket you go to anyway will be among the cheapest options and easy as well

Comment: My kids must be different from yours, becuase I *always* gave my kids a CC (along with a "conversation" about how much to spend, to keep to track, and that I'd see where they spent the money).  Never had trouble with them.

Comment: I do not have kids, so 'mine' are not a problem. But giving teens access to unlimited amounts of money and have them go out with friends has resulted in the teens spending a lot on a dare. It is not all kids, but it is a risk.

Comment: Much of Europe is cashless nowadays so I’m not sure I’d just give them cash. So much easier to just give them a debit card for an account (with a limited amount of money if you don’t trust them to handle it well.)

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek, how recent have you been a tourist in Paris? Several people in answers and comments claim cash is still needed.

Comment: @Willeke Paris no but I was in a much smaller city in France less than half a year ago. With a Europe-compatible debit card you can still withdraw the occasional pocket money in cash though.

Comment: If the kids only need a few euro for the odd snack and maybe one small souvenir, cash will be easiest. If they need more, cards or cards in addition to cash will be best. But that is now, we still do not know what the situation will be next year. (And it might be a bigger change than in any year in the past, concerning payments.)

Answer (score 8):

In most european countries, both cards and cash are widely accepted. However, "cards" means bank cards, not credit cards. Many smaller shops do **not** accept credit cards. So unless you can provide a european bank card (Girocard, EC-Card), cash is your best option. France is not one of the few countries where cash is going away, though the Corona epidemic is accelerating the trend towards cash-less payments all over Europe. On the other hand, street vendors and some small shops may not accept cards at all. In summary, that you cannot pay with a card is still more likely than that you cannot pay in cash.

Cash also has the advantage that it is more tangible. Children often do not (yet) understand money well enough to deal with it entirely in the abstract. A €10 bill is still a lot more real than a €10 card transaction. It will enable your kid to control its spending better.

You don't say how long the trip will be. If more than a week, I would consider also including a "reserve fund", which in case of emergency or unexpected expenses can be turned into cash.
This can be the old Traveler's Cheque or a debit card or something else that takes *one additional step* to make it less likely that it'll be cashed to buy some cookies (or croissants).

Comment: How much do travellers' cheques cost these days, and how easy are they to change? I used them in the 90s and even then finding an appropriate bank wasn't always easy, and the cost was significant.  Prepaid ATM cards may be better these days even for teens

Comment: In France, there is no difference between a (Visa or Mastercard) credit card or a debit/bank card in terms of acceptance, they both go through the same "Carte Bancaire" network. On the other hand, Amex, Diners, JCB, UnionPay, etc. have extremely limited acceptance (though Amex is getting better). One thing to take into account is that there's often a minimum amount for card purchases, ranging from 1 euro to 15 euros depending on the merchant. The threshold has a tendency to go down (especially since the pandemic) but there are still a few holdouts with surprisingly high thresholds.

Comment: I surprised to read that travellers cheques might still be available. I did a quick on-line search but could not find any place offering euro travellers cheques for sale.

Comment: @jcaron the minimum amount for a card payment may depend on the agreement between the merchant and the service provider. Some charge a percentage of the value and others make a fixed fee per transaction and it is (now) illegal to pass on the transaction fee to an indivdual customer. For those retailers on a percentage deal, all business is good business.

Comment: I would have given a +1 for the warning not to use a credit card, but your recommendation to use a travelers cheques would get you a -1. Those are not good anymore for people who are experienced with them. School kids who have never used them, are not familiar with the city and the language will be lost and the teachers will likely not have time to guide them to a bank that still accept them. It will be easier to give the kid a bank note of their home money and tell them that if they really need it they can ask their teacher to exchange it for them. Or the teacher can hold emergency funds.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Most merchants in France have a percentage deal and they are still reluctant to accept card payments for small amounts. This may be due to the hardship induced by the pandemic but I notice most stands at the local (farmers) market have recently raised their threshold to 10, 12, or even 20 euros. The supermarkets and most other shops have no lower limit, especially when using contactless payment.

Comment: @Xi'an there can be a reluctance to take card payments by those who don't want an audit trail. They would have to pay tax on the trading profit as well as the card handling fees.

Comment: @WeatherVane in Poland it changed somewhat after the maximum allowed percentage was lowered, but a lot of places had those minimum limits. After talking with some small shop employees and owners I've since learned that it's against card processor ToS to do so in many cases.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've updated the answer slightly to make not Traveler's Cheque but emergency reserve the focus of the last paragraph.

Comment: Better but not good yet, take out the traveller's cheques completely, they are useless for kids and teachers will likely not be able to help with them.

Comment: @jcaron > are you completely sure about that ? I'm in Belgium, not France, but I certainly know a lot of businesses that do accept debit and not credit (usually smaller shops), and others that only accept credit cards (restaurants or simply online merchants, not relevant here). While the cards indeed go into the same machine, I think this is because you can "subscribe" to either one of them, or both, with the vendor of the machine

Comment: @LaurentS. In many (possibly event most) countries, yes, there are separate systems for bank cards and credit cards, which may or may not use the same terminal, and merchants can choose to accept one or the other (there are separate merchant contracts). In France from the start of the CB system (back in the 80s), Visa and Mastercard were associated with the national system, and as far as I know all merchants (accepting cards) accept any card with either CB, Visa or Mastercard logos, this is included in the merchant contracts of all banks. Other cards (Amex etc.) are separate.

Comment: I still wouldn't be sure. My wife has a shop (not in Paris), and the cut the the processing company takes for card payments differs between credit and debit cards. If it were a shop with a thin margin, I wouldn't be surprised if they refuse one type for that reason.

Answer (score 5):

So I have been to a few school trips in foreign countries (Tho only one with a foreign currency) and my school always advised our parents to give us cash. Its easier to spot how much one has left and many smaller stores or bakeries don't accept credit card in Europe.

For the amount: I was given 100 pounds for 6 1/2 days in Great Britain about 7 years ago.

Comment: Time has moved on and now cash free payments are much more common. Amounts depend on what you have to pay for, like lunch.

Comment: Yes true but bakeries, fast food stands, crepe stands, etc still don't except credit cards in most of Europe. I haven't been to France in quite some time so that might have changed but in Germany this is still the case.

Comment: It is quite hard to find any establishment in my area of the UK which is cash only. Even market stalls take cards and at the barbers each worker has her own card machine linked to her phone.

Comment: Things have changed in 7 years. Many retail outlets in UK – even street stalls – are now card **only**. At first, burgeoning card payments were seen as unwelcome, but not any more. They solve a security issue for street traders who would have to keep the cash secure. For an individual, stolen cash has gone, but a card can be cancelled if you act quickly (and in some cases, spent money reimbursed). In fact, many people in UK no longer carry *any* cash.

Comment: Experience from the UK is kind of irrelevant here, as this varies between countries and even within the countries depending on how rural your destination is. I can definitely second @SirHawrk 's experience about cash only establishments in Germany. It would be good to get some first hand experience from France. I personally would at least make sure that my child has a way to get cash from an ATM.

Comment: @PaulPaulsen your experience in Germany is irrelevant too. OP's child is going to Paris.

Comment: @WeatherVane in the UK most of that change has been in the last year.  Pre-pandemic I had never  (literally not a single time) been unable to pay cash.

Comment: @ChrisH it's true that covid-19 accelerated the change but as long ago as 2018 I was using London street stalls with card-only payment. And I remember about 4 years ago using a sandwich van on a rural business estate where card was not mandatory but everyone (except me!) tapped their card on the reader.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, introduction of card payments at small retailers enabled the recent dropping of cash. London seemed slightly ahead of the rest of the UK in adopting contactless systems where places were previously cash-only, perhaps because of foreign visitors or the influence of the finance sector. On the other hand I've always found Londoners to carry greater quantities of cash. I'm from London but now in Bristol/Cardiff.  My barber for example didn't have a card machine a year ago. I haven't been to France since 2018 but cash was a necessity as I like a lot of snacks/coffee

Comment: @ChrisH yes, in UK retailers used to complain about low value card payments but now it's routine to tap your card for just a coffee.

Comment: @WeatherVane or phone as I'm often seeing.  I tend to only buy coffees out when on rides, and always have both options.  I still often ask what they'd prefer, as 50 cyclists descending on a (forewarned) cafe  trying to pay with notes is unhelpful.  I've also seen a lot of waste and disappointed customers when the card/phone/system wasn't playing nicely.  The fee for contactless is much less than card fees used to be, accelerating the switch

Comment: France specifically: certainly in 2019 paying for a snack at (e.g.) a market stall in France was likely to mean cash.  The last bakery I went in would take cards but everyone buying small amounts used cash - there may have been a minimum card spend.  I would expect Paris to be more card-based (it's a few years since I went but cards were more widely used there than in rural areas) but no cash at all could still lead to disappointment

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, my experience from Germany is not more relevant than yours from the UK and was merely given as a counterexample to show that things might be different elsewhere. If you read my comment closely you might even see that I asked for first-hand experience from France, as I would argue that's the important bit :)

Comment: So I'd like to say that the last time I was in France was September of 2019  and when I went to get breakfast the bakery only accepted cash

Comment: Permanent shops which do not accept cards at all are exceedingly rare nowadays, though many still have minimum payment amounts, anywhere between 1 and 15 euros (most often 5 or 10, though there's a downwards trend). Market stalls and street vendors are more likely not to accept cards, though this is also becoming less common.

Comment: @SirHawrk I found that in Germany card payments have increased since the pandemic started.  My local bakery (Rhein-Main area) introduced card payments this year for the first time.

Comment: Yes some bakeries started doing that but most local fast food joints (döner) still dont

Answer (score 0):

Check with the school. They will likely provide guidance on this nearer the time anyway, along with information about what your child needs to bring with them (and what they should not - e.g. expensive electronics or jewellery).

Many school trips recommend cash and operate a bank system. Before departing, each child gives the teacher the majority of their foreign currency and the teacher looks after it for the duration of the trip (often along with their passports). At regular intervals there will be an opportunity for each student to withdraw cash from the teacher's bank. Typically this would be at breakfast/dinner time, or immediately before a shopping trip.

Source: I have accompanied trips with several UK schools.